# Laravel 5 Commands - dispatch command pipeline

Tags: command, pipeline, laravel-5

Is it possible to create a sort of command pipeline when dispatching a command?

For instance:

`$this->dispatch(new UploadFileCommand)` would call `ValidateFileCommand`, `WhateverCommand`.

It's like `pipeThrough` but triggers specific commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After talking to some people, I realized I was overthinking this. The solution is simpler than I was imagining. To pipe through commands, just do:

```
public function whateverMethod(Dispatcher $dispacher) {
  $dispached->pipeThrough([]) // arrays with commands 
}
```

Dispacher comes through beautiful laravel 5 method injection!

Answer (score 1):

I know you asked this a while ago but thought I'd answer anyway.

> artisan make:middleware WhateverPipeline

You would then have to add

> use DispatchesCommands;

Then

> $this->dispatch(new WhateverCommand());

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesCommands;

class WhateverPipeline {
    use DispatchesCommands;

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $this->dispatch(new WhateverCommand());
        return $next($request);
    }

}
```

The WhateverCommand would have to not be a queue command to be executed there and then in the pipeline.

You can also dispatch any commands from within WhateverCommand with

> use DispatchesCommands;